# Is it possible to replicate asp-for behavior?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I created a view component that needs as a parameter the name of the input generated when using "asp-for".
For example this case:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="InputModel.Description" />
```

I need in the code behind to have a string with the value "InputModel.Description". 
I tried using nameof() but that only returns "Description".
Any ideas?

Comment: Can't you use Reflection to get the Type name?

Comment: Would it work in cases like "InputModel.Description.FullDetails" ? I need this feature to be dynamic independently of the value

Comment: You could call GetType() on whatever it is you are passing to nameof.

Comment: Scratch that, it was dumb of me to say that.

Comment: GetType() only works with the class name, doesnt work with the name of the instance